# Website allows to paste directly image in a HTML textbox

Tags: html, image

I noticed an unexpected feature on the specific website wrike.com. Not sure why I've gotten those downvotes.

In the app, there's a large text box for each tasks, when I paste a copied image inside, it inserts the image inline right away (e.g. doing the upload and insert in where my cursor in one shot transparently upon paste).

I repeat, no java applets, no flash plugins, no silverlight. Copying the image itself, and pasting it in the field pastes the image successfully. My initial guess is that it's HTML 5. I've never seen this before, and I was genuinely wondering how this was done.

Here are some images of it happening:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you visibly see an upload take place? (ie. something in the network logs, or a "space" that later turns into an image). If not you may find that when you `copy` an image, that you're actually copying its `base64` data, so when it's pasted the inline `img` is actually loading the image data from a `base64` string rather than a file containing it. Just a thought

Comment: @Jason yes the website is wrike.com. Open a task, and in the task description, you can paste images and text alike.

Comment: @haxxxton yes I'm thinking this might be related

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon closer inspection, they are using [EtherPad Lite](https://github.com/ether/etherpad-lite) to handle the description section. And they are leveraging the [ep_copy_paste_images](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ep_copy_paste_images) npm package to handle the image paste uploading.

[image]
*Note: some details hidden in image for security*

From what i can see, it makes a `POST` request (**Annotation A**) with the `base64` encoded data (**Annotation B**) to their server. Upon completion, it makes a new request to get the attachment identifier of the newly created image on the server (**Annotation C**). It then replaces the placeholder with a `img` with the returned src which loads the new image based off the response from **C** (**Annotation D**)

Comment: I didn't know browsers would translate pasted images into base64 data to the browser. First time I see this.

Comment: Some documentation I found so far
https://github.com/ether/etherpad-lite/issues/2227
https://github.com/JohnMcLear/ep_copy_paste_images

Comment: @WadihM., hahah yep, just found that myself, added to my answer

Comment: seems it's not such an uncommon feature. https://www.tinymce.com/ seems to have it as well!