# How Can I Let Users Paste Image Data Into An HTML Form?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, image

I currently have an HTML form that gets a file from a user and then it will do things with that file in PHP. How can I make it so a user can paste image data using CTRL+V and it will input that image data into the HTML form? I would assume I need javascript.

Comment: this site allows the pasting of image data into questions and answers ... explore that

Comment: that does not help me one bit @jsotola

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Website allows to paste directly image in a HTML textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41947051/website-allows-to-paste-directly-image-in-a-html-textbox)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Paste image from clipboard to web form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10251528/paste-image-from-clipboard-to-web-form)